# Why I can't set cookie?

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I'm coding a basic website and I want to set a cookie named 'color' at the beginning of the session.

For that mean, I used this code :

```
<?php 
require_once("../model/connection.php");

if (!(empty($_POST['user_email'])) and !(empty($_POST['user_password']))){

    $login = $_POST['user_email'];
    $password = $_POST['user_password'];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT ID, color FROM Player WHERE mail = ? AND password = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$login,$password);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {

        session_start();
        $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
        $_SESSION['ID'] = $row['ID'];
        setcookie("color", $row['color'], time() + 365*24*3600) or die('unable to create cookie');

        header("Location: ../view/index.php");
    }

}
else {
    header("Location: ../view/index.php?error=false");
}
```

But when I call var_dump('$_COOKIE['color'], php returns

> Notice: Undefined index: color in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/controller/controller_game.php on line 7

There is certainly a basic thing I don't understand, sorry I'm a beginner.

By the way, my request is good, I tested it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Cookie is available on second page load.

Comment: From [the setcookie() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php): "_Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE array._"

Answer (score 0):

Add the last parameter **/** and it should work. As follows

```
setcookie("color", $row['color'], time() + 365*24*3600, "/");
```

Hope this helps